# Ember with videoJS function calling

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, video.js

I am using videoJS player and ember in my application . I am calling VideoJs function(javascript function) inside didInsertelement callback (after template is rendered) . When i enter video id in browser (with url) ,it goes inside didInsertelement and videojs function is called and it display well . The problem i encounter is when i enter another video id , only content is changed and didInsertelement callback is not called . So it retains old video source .

this is my view component

```
App.VideoField=Ember.View.extend({
tagName:'video',
attributeBindings:['preload','autoplay',"src","controls","width","height"],
didInsertElement:function(){
  var interval_obj;
  var video_obj=this;
  console.log(this.get('elementId'))
  videojs(this.get('elementId'),{"controls":true,"width":"auto","height":"auto","nativeControlsForTouch":false},function(){
    var current_player=this; 

    current_player.on("pause", function(){

        current_player.bigPlayButton.show();
        //video_obj.$('#vjs-image-overlay-holder').removeClass('display-none');
        //tooltip issue when video is in fullscreen
        current_player.on("fullscreenchange",function(){

          video_obj.$("#vjs-tip-white").css({"left":""+Math.floor(video_obj.$('.vjs-play-progress').width()-(video_obj.$('#vjs-tip-white').width())/2)+'px'});
        });
        //clearing interval and set playerStatus to false
        clearInterval(interval_obj);
        //video_obj.get('controller').set('playerStatus',false);
    });

    current_player.on("play", function(){ 

      //video_obj.$('#vjs-image-overlay-holder').addClass('display-none');
      current_player.bigPlayButton.hide();

      interval_obj=setInterval(function(){
        // the changing constraint for every one minute current_player.currentTime()
        video_obj.get('controller').set('playerStatus',current_player.currentTime());
      },1000*60);

    });

    //Added overlay for smooth scroll over html5-video element and touch events to work
    var html5_overlay=document.createElement('div');
    html5_overlay.setAttribute('class','full-html5-overlay-video');
    current_player.el().appendChild(html5_overlay);

    video_obj.$().on('click','.full-html5-overlay-video',function(e){
      if(current_player.paused()){
          current_player.play();
        }
        else{
          current_player.pause();
        }
    });
    //Black tooltip only for desktop(having some issues in touch devices)
    current_player.progressTips();
    current_player.on('ended',function(){
      //clearing interval and set playerStatus to false
      clearInterval(interval_obj);

      //video_obj.get('controller').set('playerStatus',false);
    });
  });
}


});
```

In template i am rendering like this

```
{{view App.VideoField srcBinding="src" id="sample_video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin yg_video" preload="metadata"}}
```

After render the html content will be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

didInsertElement hook is only fired when the element is injected into the dom.

You can override the setupController/afterModel hook in the route, those will be called each time.

If you need it to run after the page is finished rendering, you can schedule it.

```
App.MyRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  afterModel: function(resolvedModel, transition, queryParams){
    // do it here
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model); // do default implementation
    // or do it here
  }
});

Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
  //executes after the page is done rendering
});
```

You can add an observer watching the content and if it changes fire the changes again

```
watchSrcOrContent: function(){

}.observes('content', 'src', 'whateverproperty')
```

Comment: thanks kingpin2 , it is long function . Inside that function i am using some player functions .

Comment: Or can i create ember video component ?

Comment: You definitely can create an ember component, if you're going to be using it in more than one place and you want to be more modular it's a great practice.

Comment: I can't call videoJs function inside after model because i need to pass video-id . Videojs function will modify dom content.

Comment: give me any suggestions?

Comment: you can schedule an `afterRender` in `init` of your component

Comment: I just edit the question ... view is called only once so ,videojs function is not called if content changes

Comment: I don't know ember well, but whenever you're using videos in a dynamic app like this, make sure you're calling player.dispose() when you're done with a video. Also you don't have to pass an ID to the video.js function specifically. You could pass the video element itself.

Comment: @kingpin2k, if i call videojs function inside conroller property , it will call before video element render...

Comment: did you try scheduling it from within the controller property?  using the scheduler above?

Comment: ya i tried , it is showing "id" is not valid error(since i need to pass video id for videoJS function) .

Comment: Since i am using Ember data , once it loads data , next time it will not go to view and template (Only content is changed ).

Comment: do you have a jsbin i could understand it better?   i just had shoulder surgery, so it'll take me a while, slow typing and awesome drugs